# Como fazer a tela de instruções de uso ao iniciar um app

Tags: android

Quando baixamos um app, muitas vezes ao iniciar ele apresenta uma tela (ou várias) de instruções de uso do próprio app?! Gostaria de saber como se faz aquilo. Se não puderem colocar algum endereço de código ou tutorial, pelo menos o nome correto para que possa pesquisar!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esta apresentação é chamado de `Tour`, `User Onboarding` ou `App Intro`. Recomendo a utilização da biblioteca [AppIntro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=paolorotolo.github.com.appintroexample), já segue todos os aspectos para uma ótima introdução para o seu aplicativo.

Você pode encontrar um [exemplo através desta aplicação na `Play Store`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=paolorotolo.github.com.appintroexample).

**Referências**:

Github: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

Loja: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=paolorotolo.github.com.appintroexample

Comment: Muito boa as referencias @sicachester, vou utilizar!

Comment: Obrigado @sicachester por responder e pela dica!

Comment: Apenas complementando: essa apresentação também pode ser chamada de user Onboarding

Comment: @LeonardoAssunção adicionado na resposta! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tente estes dois:

[RoboDemo](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo)

[ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) Este não está mais em desenvolvimento mas pode ser util.

Comment: Você sabe o nome dessa técnica? fiquei interessado :)@CelsoMarigoJr

Comment: Obrigado por responder Celso.. vou testar aqui e retorno para fechar a pergunta

Comment: @Wellington Avelino, Procurei por "android make a tutorial" no google :p ... Na verdade tenho alguns projetos em android mas nenhum está nessa fase ainda. A pergunta também me deixou curioso por isso procurei.

Comment: @Tairone Dias, ... é um assunto bastante interessante para qualquer desenvolvedor android. Poste sim se deu certo!

Comment: Deu uma pesquisada aqui alguns chamam de `showCase` outros de `DemoActivity`, encontrei isso no SOen 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/11805890/3861347

http://stackoverflow.com/q/12013334/3861347

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr conseguir utilizar inicialmente o Showcase View, porém para o que queria em si, foi mais interessante o post de sicachester com a utilização do AppIntro. Da mesma forma lhe agradeço pela atenção!

Comment: @TaironeDias também achei a resposta dele melhor... Mas, obrigado pelo feedback!